# a scoring system for a prediction game

Tags: probability

lets assume we have a prediction game for whenever of not an event would happen
basically a Bernoulli random variable with probability ($p$), ($p$ is unknown, thats what the players have to guess).

let say we score like this: each contestant gives its guess of p, lets say some player guesses $p_g$
if the event happens the player gets $p_g$ points, otherwise he gets $1-p_g$.

is this the optimal scoring system so that the best strategy for the players would be to guess $p_g= p_{private}$ if $p >.5$ otherwise guess $p_g =1-p_{private}$

lets say for example p=0.8
the expected value of the score is:
$E[X] = .8 p_g + .2 (1-p_g) = 0.6p_g +0.2$

meaning the  optimal guess is actually $p_g =1$

but when i [entered this equation into wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%20*%20(p)%20%2B%20(1-x)*(1-p)%20,%200%3Cx%3C1,0%3Cp%3C1,%20maximum)
i got exactly what i wanted in the answer

i am not sure what went wrong

EDIT: ill try to explain my self

i am denoting:

$p_{private}$ - the players internal estimation for $p$.

$p_g$ - the players guess that he gives in order to be scored.

with my previous suggestion for a scoring system ($p_g$ if the event occurs, $1-p_g$ otherwise), the best strategy would be to either choose $p_g = 1/0$ depending on if $p_{private} >0.5$ ! (if the player internally belives that $p>0.5$ he should choose $p_g$ =1, oterwise he should choose $p_g$ =0)

i would like a scoring system so that the players strategy would be to just propose what actually estimated p to be (e.g $p_g =p_{private}$)

Comment: Is there a `game master' who knows the true value of $p$? Or does nobody know this?

Comment: p is unknown, we can only observe if the event happened or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is called a [scoring rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule). One example of a scoring rule is the quadratic (proper) scoring rule. In your setting, this essentially involves setting a player's payoff function to be

$$ -(X-p_g)^2, $$

where $X$ is your Bernoulli random variable. Players then choose $p_g$ to maximise

\begin{align*}
-\hat{\mathbb{E}}\left[(X-p_g)^2\right] &= -\hat{p}(1-p_g)^2-(1-\hat{p})(-p_g)^2 \\
&= -\hat{p}(1-2p_g + p_g^2) -p_g^2 + \hat{p}p_g^2 \\
&= -\hat p +2 \hat p p_g - \hat p p_g^2 -p_g^2 + \hat p p_g^2 \\
&= -\hat{p} + 2\hat{p}p_g - p_g^2
\end{align*}

Here, I use $\hat{\mathbb{E}}$ to denote taking expectation with respect to the probability measure given by the player's private belief $\hat{p}$. That is, $\hat{p}$ is the player's private belief that the event will happen (i.e. $X=1$). In your notation, $\hat p = p_{\text{private}}$.

You can then check that expected payoffs are maximised by setting

$$ p_g = \hat p. $$

Of course, the quadratic scoring rule is only one example of such a rule. You can read about others in the article I linked above.

Comment: the payoff is always negative, meaning the best possible score is 0?

Comment: @guynaa In my example, yes. If you don't like that, you can add a constant to the payoff function that will guarantee that payoffs are positive -- this will not change the choice of $p_g$ that maximises payoffs.

Comment: thank this, this is exactly what i was looking for, although when i tried calculating $\hat{\mathbb{E}}$ i got something different, could you please show the steps in the middle of the calculation?

Comment: @guynaa There aren't really any steps to show there, so I'm not sure what you mean by that. Could you tell me what expression you got instead? That will help me figure out what needs to be explained. It might help if you chose numbers for $\hat{p}$ (or $p_{\text{private}}$) before making the calculation for $\hat{\mathbb{E}}$.

Comment: without the minus: $E[(X-p_g)^2] = E[X^2] - 2p_gE[X] + p_g^2 = p_{private}^2 -2p_gp_{private} + p_g^2$

Comment: @guynaa $\hat{\mathbb{E}} \left[ X^2 \right]=\hat{p}\cdot 1^2 + (1-\hat{p})\cdot 0^2 = \hat{p}$.

Comment: my mistake but this is still different from your result: $E[(X-p_g)^2] = E[X^2] + 2p_gE[X] + p_g^2 = \hat p + 2p_g\hat p +p_g^2$

Comment: @guynaa You've made a sign error that wasn't there in your first comment. $\hat{\mathbb{E}}\left[(X-p_g)^2\right]=\hat{p} - 2\hat{p}p_g + p_g^2$. This expression is the same as the one in my answer after simplifcation.

Comment: thank you, everything is clear now!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain about all the notation you introduce as I don't think you defined $p_{\text{private}}$, but hopefully this still answers the question.

Denoting $p$ for the unknown true probability of the game, $p_g$ as the player's guess, and $X$ the points scored, then the expected return is

$$ \mathbf E[X] = pp_g + (1-p)(1-p_g).$$

Note that this is a linear function in $p_g$ and as such has its maximum at either end point; i.e. the optimal strategy is to choose $p_g\in \{0,1\}$. However whether the optimal point is $0$ or $1$ depends on whether or not $p > \frac12$.

If it is known (as you assume in your question) that $p > \frac12$ then the player should use $p_g = 1$.

If on the other hand this is not known, and the player is best to assume that $p$ could be any number between $0$ and $1$, then the strategy does not matter. To see this we note that if our belief is that the parameter is uniformly distributed, $p \sim \text{Unif}[0,1]$, then the expected return is given by

\begin{align*}
\mathbf E[X] & = \int_0^1 \mathbf E[X \, | \, p = \theta] \mathbf P[p = \theta] d\theta \\
& = \int_0^1 \theta p_g+ (1-\theta)(1-p_g) d \theta \\
& = \frac12,
\end{align*}
that is, the expectation is $\frac12$ regardless of the choice of $p_g$.

Comment: thanks you for your response, but its not exactly what i wanted to know, i used $p_{private}$ to denote the player internal probability when he tries to asses $p$. and i wanted to find an optimal scoring system so that the best strategy for the player would be to guess their private estimation $p_{private}$. as you pointed out in my (bad) scoring system, the player should choose 1 if they belive $p>.5$ (e.g $p_{private}>0.5$).

Comment: I find it hard to see this from your original post, and even the description you give now is confusing to me. Can you please update your question to clarify what you are asking?